# Trouble with @font-face css rule

Tags: css, font-face, custom-font

Cannot get my installed font to work with my css. I have tried absolutely everything. I have a feeling it might be my file structure. but i know that is where my font is located on my computer. any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="webdesign.html">Web Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="photography.html">Photography</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: jaapokki;
    src: src("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/custom/jaapokkisubtract-regular.ttf");
    font-weight: normal;
 }

/***********************************
Main Layout
***********************************/


body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #A4A4A6;
    font-family: jaapokki;
}

.header {
    height: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: solid 30px #7300B5;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;

}

 .content {
    width: 960px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 2000px;
    margin: 70px auto; 
}

/***********************************
  Header Navigation
***********************************/

 .navigation li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px 20px;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;

 }

 .navigation li a {
     text-decoration: none;

 }
```

Please Help!

Comment: you have to serve it relative to the css on your web server - not your absolute file system path.

Comment: so i should add it next to my css file like this: "../fonts/jaapokkisubtract-regular.ttf"?

Comment: perhaps. it all depends.

Answer (score 0):

The src attribute actually tells the browser where to look for the font file on the server. You've to place the path inside the quote marks and inside `url()` like this

```
@font-face
{
font-family: "League Gothic";
src: url('../fonts/leagure_fonts.ttf');
}
```

The path works like your HTML paths for eg. javascript files, images etc... Consider you had a style sheets inside a folder names _styles and font file named League.ttf inside a folder named _fonts. Both the folders are in the root of your site.

So the style sheet path would be `../_fonts/League.ttf.` If you want to make more clear(or in case of multiple src attributes) then try this one also

```
@font-face
    {
    font-family: "League Gothic";
    src: url('../fonts/league_fonts.ttf')format('truetype');
    }
```

If you're using IE 8 or below or IE 9 in compatibility mode then this may help you because of IE bugs. Need to append `?#iefix`

```
@font-face
    {
    font-family: "League Gothic";
    src: url('../fonts/league_fonts.eot?#iefix')format('embedded-opentype')
    }
```

**Modify as per your requirements**